# Twig include and pass a boolean value?

Tags: twig

Im my page template I'm including my component template and passing it a number of values. One of these "mod" is a simple true or false value:

In component.twig:

```
{% if mod == true %}
  <h1>Mod is true</h1>
{% endif %}
```

In page.twig:

```
{% include "component.html.twig" with {mod: true, style: 'main', title: 'title' } %}
```

This is working but is there a shorter way of writing the include? I tried this:

```
{% include "component.html.twig" with {mod, style: 'main', title: 'title' } %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. `{% if mod == true %}` can be shortend to `{% if mod %}` though.